How to handle GP Tool execution result asynchronously in ArcGIS Engine with Background 64bit
I am using ArcGIS Engine with background 64bit and calling GP tools using the ExecuteAsync event. I want to continue processing the results of the GP tool execution after it finishes. Following the official example of gp.ToolExecuted to monitor the execution status of the GP tool, I noticed that the event within gp.ToolExecuted is triggered only after the main function completes. How can I modify my code to handle the GP tool's results immediately after execution, without waiting for the main function to finish?
private async void btnRunGP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        #region tidy up any previous gp runs
        //Clear the ListView control
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        //Remove any result layers present in the map
        IMapLayers mapLayers = axMapControl1.Map as IMapLayers;
        foreach (IFeatureLayer resultLayer in _resultsList)
        {
            mapLayers.DeleteLayer(resultLayer);
        }
        axTOCControl1.Update();
        
        _resultsList.Clear();
        
        _myGPToolsToExecute.Clear();
        #endregion
        ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Buffer bufferTool = new ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Buffer();
        bufferTool.in_features = _layersDict["Cities"];
        bufferTool.buffer_distance_or_field = txtBufferDistance.Text + " Miles";
        bufferTool.out_feature_class = "city_buffer.shp";
        ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Clip clipTool = new ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Clip();
        clipTool.in_features = _layersDict["ZipCodes"];
        clipTool.clip_features = bufferTool.out_feature_class;
        clipTool.out_feature_class = "city_buffer_clip.shp";
        _myGPToolsToExecute.Enqueue(bufferTool);
        _myGPToolsToExecute.Enqueue(clipTool);
         _gp.ExecuteAsync(_myGPToolsToExecute.Dequeue());
        //I want to do something after executeAsync,but I dont want to put them in ToolExecuted
        MessageBox.show("finish")

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[2] { "N/A", ex.Message }, "error"));
    }
}
void _gp_ToolExecuted(object sender, ToolExecutedEventArgs e)
{
    IGeoProcessorResult2 gpResult = (IGeoProcessorResult2)e.GPResult;

    try
    {
        //The first GP tool has completed, if it was successful process the others
        if (gpResult.Status == esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[2] { "ToolExecuted", gpResult.Process.Tool.Name }, "success"));

            //Execute next tool in the queue
            if (_myGPToolsToExecute.Count > 0)
            {
                _gp.ExecuteAsync(_myGPToolsToExecute.Dequeue());
            }
            //If last tool has executed add the output layer to the map
            else
            {
                IFeatureClass resultFClass = _gp.Open(gpResult.ReturnValue) as IFeatureClass;
                IFeatureLayer resultLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
                resultLayer.FeatureClass = resultFClass;
                resultLayer.Name = resultFClass.AliasName;

                //Add the result to the map
                axMapControl1.AddLayer((ILayer)resultLayer, 2);
                axTOCControl1.Update();

                //add the result layer to the List of result layers
                _resultsList.Add(resultLayer);
            }
        }
        //If the GP process failed, do not try to process any more tools in the queue
        else if (gpResult.Status == esriJobStatus.esriJobFailed)
        {
            //The actual GP error message will be output by the MessagesCreated event handler
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[2] { "ToolExecuted", gpResult.Process.Tool.Name + " failed, any remaining processes will not be executed." }, "error"));
            //Empty the queue
            _myGPToolsToExecute.Clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[2] { "ToolExecuted", ex.Message }, "error"));
    }
}

I also tried adding a while loop to block the GP tool execution until it completes, but the gp.Execute function didn't execute at all—it kept looping.
What should I do to handle this situation?
_gp.ExecuteAsync(_myGPToolsToExecute.Dequeue());
while(!isDone){}
    //I want to do something after executeAsync,but I dont want to put them in ToolExecuted
    MessageBox.show("finish")

